# How to test the effect between income and economic growth in spss?

Tags: regression, distributions, correlation, normal-distribution, spss

am going to test the impact and relationship between income, which is an independent variable, and economic growth, which is a dependent variable, over 10 years in spss?
Thanks

Comment: economic growth impacts income, it's not a one way relationship

Answer (score 0):

You could start with a simple linear regression model. It will show you the relationship between income and growth. I am assuming you are interested in the effects of **per capita income on economic growth**.

You might want to include some control variables because per capita income is not the only variable that affects growth. For instance, investment should have a strong relationship with growth.

Since you are dealing with time-series data, you can also check for stationarity of your variables. If they are non-stationary, your linear regression results may not be reliable.
But if you are dealing with yearly data, you only have 10 observations. Your choice of models will be very limited because your observations are low. If it is monthly or quarterly data, you could try ARIMA models for forecasting.